# Inserting math, brackets etc

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm kinda new here. May I know how I can insert math here? For example, matrices and the Greek alphabet?
Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm honestly clueless.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:  [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

MathJax is how it's all done.  If you already know Latex you're $75\%$ of the way there.

Comment: The very simple introduction is a help page called [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).